# Japanese characters for autosuggestion field

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

First of all, I'm not from Japan and I don't have knowledge about Japanese writting.

I need to develop an autosuggest field, like the autocomplete widget from jquery UI.

The suggestion should be presented to the user as he is typing. I know that there is a conversion between latin characters, Hiragana and Kanji. Until that conversion happens, there should be no suggestion presented.

What will be the best practice to implement such a functionality?

Also, is there a way in JavaScript to distinguish between Hiragana and Kanji characters?

Comment: As far as you can distinguish Latin and Cyrillic same scenario applies on Hiragana and Kanji or whatever. These are maps of characters.
If you recognize a character of a collection you trigger the auto-suggest for it.

Comment: However It isn't just a matter of characters because let's say some  participate in both collections how a distinguish is made in such case? For instance `a` is Latin and Cyrillic char. These is a big issue you should examine carefully and look and read for solutions.
The key is the `unicode` standard for sure

Comment: @kidwon, identically looking Latin and Cyrillic characters have different Unicode code points. `'a' != 'а' && 'a'.charCodeAt(0) != 'а'.charCodeAt(0)`.